# Examples of 1 and 2 dimensional.

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

I understand that the x-axis alone is 1 dimensional. 
Throw in the y-axis and there are 2 dimensions.  Add a z-axis and
there are 3 dimensions.  Overall I have a good understanding of
dimensions.  A line is 1 dimensional, a square or rectangle is 2
dimensional, and a cube is 3 dimensional.

My question is what if you throw in parabolas or circles or the
absolute value function, etc.?  A parabola can only be drawn in
2-space, but lines are also drawn in 2-space unless the slope is 0 or
does not exist.  A circle is kind of like a parabola, but it is very
much like a square, so I am thinking it is 2-dimensional.  My
conclusion is that the only 1 dimensional object is a straight line,
and a point is 0 dimensional, but I am not confident that I am
correct.  Can you please clear this up for me?

Comment: You are making a buttload of assumptions, are you dealing with ordinary euclidean space or something else? There are spaces where dimensions are meaningless and you still can have something called a circle and even in ordinary fmailiar spaces a circle and square might be one and the same due to the metric and so on.

Comment: from 3 dimensional object, you might find parts which are 2 or 1 dimensional...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you talk of a circle you have to make the distinction between (a) circle along with interior usually called a disc and (2) circle with just its circumference. The former is a 2-dimensional object and the latter is a 1-dimensional object. Evev though a point on the circumeference of a circle needs two co-oordinates to specify, if you see careflly only one co-ordinate is free.

By this I mean, take a circle of radius 5 centred at origin, if you know the $x$ co-ordinate to be 2, then y co-ordinate is forced to be $\sqrt{25-4}=\sqrt{21}$.

The dimension is technically defined as the number of  *independent* parameters  that are needed to describe the points of a shape. (This is algebro-geometric viewpoint. In topology dimension is defined as what you see when you look only at close enough points. In a circle you will see a small arc which is 1-dimensional. Some insect crawling on a soap bubble will see (when myopic) only a disc, hence a soap bubble is 2-dimensional (a surface).

Answer (score 0):

> $x$-axis alone is 1 dimensional. Throw in the $y$-axis and there are 2 dimensions. Add a $z$-axis and there are 3 dimensions.

A rough version of the usual notion of dimension indeed is the following: The number of lines can you draw through a point so that they are all perpendicular to each other (think about the origin and the coordinate axes). The more precise way to say this is to define [bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) and look at their sizes.

> My question is what if you throw in parabolas or circles or the absolute value function, etc.?

When you go beyond flat things (vector spaces), you need to be more careful. I think that [*differential geometry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry) is the field of mathematics that would, in a way, answer this question. If you consider those shapes as "manifolds", all of them are one dimensional objects.

One alternative notion of dimension is also [the Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) which is defined even for some extremely irrelgular objects.